# eclipselink cache on the object relationship

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class CustomerMainInformation {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;

@Column(unique = true, length = 10)
private String customerNumber;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "firstCustomerRelationship", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CustomerRelationship> firstCustomerRelationship;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "secondCustomerRelationship", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<CustomerRelationship> secondCustomerRelationship;
// setter & getter
}

@Entity
public class CustomerRelationship {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "first")
private CustomerMainInformation firstCustomerRelationship;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(columnDefinition = "second")
private CustomerMainInformation secondCustomerRelationship;

// setter & getter
}
```

I executed following code:

```
    CustomerMainInformation customerMainInformation =manager.getReference(CustomerMainInformation.class, 1L);
    System.out.println(customerMainInformation.getFirstCustomerRelationship().size());
    System.out.println(customerMainInformation.getSecondCustomerRelationship().size());

    CustomerMainInformation customerMainInformation2 = manager.getReference(customerMainInformation.getClass(), 2L);
    CustomerRelationship customerRelationship = new CustomerRelationship();
    customerRelationship.setFirstCustomerRelationship(customerMainInformation2);
    customerRelationship.setSecondCustomerRelationship(customerMainInformation);
    manager.persist(customerRelationship);
    transaction.commit();

    EntityManager manager2 = factory.createEntityManager();
    CustomerMainInformation customerMainInformation3 =  manager2.getReference(CustomerMainInformation.class, 1L);
    System.out.println(customerMainInformation3.getFirstCustomerRelationship().size());
    System.out.println(customerMainInformation3.getSecondCustomerRelationship().size());
```

In this code relationship size increment but because .getSecondCustomerRelationship() before called, list size not changed.

If @Cacheable(false) add to CustomerRelationship the .size() return correct list size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be maintaining both sides of your relationships in the code shown.  Calling setSecondCustomerRelationship Will set one side of it, and this side controls the foreign key field in the db. But your java object model is out of sync with your changes unless you also add the customerRelationship to customerMainInformation's collection.  JPA does not maintain your relationships for you, so if you change one side, you are responsible for keeping the other side insync.

You can either set both sides, or force the customerMainInformation to be refreshed from the database after you commit.  The first option is far more efficient.